# Graph Coloring Problem in Prolog : Program not terminating

Tags: prolog, graph-coloring

```
vertex(1).
vertex(2).
vertex(3).
vertex(4).

color(1).
color(2).
color(3).

edge(1,2).
edge(1,3).
edge(1,4).
edge(2,4).
edge(3,4).
edge(X,Y):-edge(Y,X).

getelement(1,[Z|_],Z).
getelement(X,[Z|Zs],M):-K is X-1,getelement(K,Zs,M).

check(Z):-edge(X,Y),getelement(X,Z,M),getelement(Y,Z,N),M=:=N,!,fail.


getcolor(1,red).
getcolor(2,blue).
getcolor(3,green).


colorit([A,B,C,D]):-color(A),color(B),color(C),color(D),write([A,B,C,D]),check([A,B,C,D]),write([A,B,C,D]).
```

This is my code. The problem it is not getting terminated. But the logic in code is clear, if you find where problem exists please help me to correct.

input:- colorit(Z).

```
output:- [1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 2]
[1, 1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3]
```

it came till here, [1,2,2,3] which is the true solution it is in loop and not terminating by returning true.There's just a small correction that need to be made. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes on your code:

- The rule `edge(X,Y):-edge(Y,X).` creates an infinite search tree.

  Instead use `hasEdge(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y) ; edge(Y,X).`

  This means `hasEdge(X,Y)` is true when `edge(X,Y)` or `edge(Y,X)` is true. 
  Then replace the usage of `edge` in your `check` predicate by `hasEdge`.
- Your definition of check provides no positive case. You say: When there is an edge between the vertices `X` and `Y` such that the `X`th and `Y`th element of the coloring list `Z` are equal, then fail. But you provide no way for `check` to be true when this condition does not hold, so this path will also fail. For this, add a `check(Z).` declaration *after* your `check` rule (analogous to how yo would define the `not` predicate, see [here](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_5.html)). Even shorter, you could remove the fail path altogether and just use `not` in your definition of `colorize`.

Based on these observations, your program could be rewritten to (I'm skipping the facts):

```
hasEdge(X,Y):-edge(X,Y) ; edge(Y,X).

getelement(1,[Z|_],Z).
getelement(X,[Z|Zs],M):-K is X-1,getelement(K,Zs,M).

check(Z):-hasEdge(X,Y),getelement(X,Z,M),getelement(Y,Z,N),M=:=N,!,fail.
check(Z).

colorit([A,B,C,D]):-color(A),color(B),color(C),color(D),check([A,B,C,D]).
```

Or using `not`:

```
hasEdge(X,Y):-edge(X,Y) ; edge(Y,X).

getelement(1,[Z|_],Z).
getelement(X,[Z|Zs],M):-K is X-1,getelement(K,Zs,M).

check(Z):-hasEdge(X,Y),getelement(X,Z,M),getelement(Y,Z,N),M=:=N.

colorit([A,B,C,D]):-color(A),color(B),color(C),color(D),not(check([A,B,C,D])).
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured out, even if we remove the edge(X, Y):-edge(Y, X). worked perfectly. Yeah, the reason is correct, it is undergoing infinite loop. If Possible please upvote the question, so that many get the correct solution.